# Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want know how many times people clicked on a particular button (should be very simple with Google analytics).
However, I had an "Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined" error from google console and can't find how to fix it.

I added this in the head:

```
     <script>

      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
      [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto') ; 

      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

And add an onclick event on the button by generating the code with this tool http://gaconfig.com/google-analytics-event-tracking/contact-form/ :

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Book button', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'enquiry home page'});"
```

Then I set up the goals in google analytics, but still have this error in the console.

So I tried to add:

```
var gaq = gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Before declaring the google analytics function, but it generates a second error so I just dropped it.

Does anyone know if the problem comes from the script I'm using? Or if it is from the onclick event code?

Comment: When you load your HTML up and enter `ga` in javascript console, do you get a function() or undefined?

Comment: Your code with gaq won't work because that is for classic GA and is not compatible with UA library that you are including (analytics.js). Also, in your code above, try to remove the line break.

Comment: I removed the line break and the gaq code. It's still not working. Is that maybe because I have two same goals on the same page? 
Category and event are the same, only the label is different between them.

Comment: Just sort out the problem! It's because it is an old website (coded by someone else) that has <head> tags everywhere and I didn't notice it. The code is alright, it was just a failed structure of the website. Thanks everybody for the help!

Answer (score 22):

I created a simple HTML with the same JS and click handler and ran it in my local apache server, it just works fine. Don't see any reference errors.

Make sure you don't have AdBlocker or other software preventing tracking which might be blocking the GoogleAnalytics
`

```
 <script>

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
    [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto') ; 

    ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>

<input type= "button" value ="Click Me" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Book button', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'enquiry home page'});"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, just didn't call the analytics script in the right head.

Answer (score 4):

The same problem occured in my Wordpress website.
I had event tracking code in my contact form 7 additional field, but after I installed the plugin Monster Insights I had to delete the code in the Theme Options. Forgetting the code in my contact forms, I got this message too.

So delete all tracking code if you start using this plugin.
Hope someone finds this information usefull..

Comment: THANK YOU! I was at wit's end why it wasn't working. As soon as I deactivated Monster Insights plugin and got another plugin to do the Google Analytics integration for me, it worked!

Comment: MonsterInsights doesn't track site owners by default to prevent them from skewing their own GA data. Always try code in the incognito mode.

Answer (score 4):

Open a new incognito window. If you are logged in then the analytics code won't be ran. Also instead of "ga" you need to use "__gaTracker" for some reason Monster Insights doesn't use "ga" they change it to "__gaTracker".

Answer (score 3):

You settled this question already but I just wanted to add:

Make sure your browser is allowing sites to track you. If you disallow tracking, the Google Analytics JS file will not load and you may get this error

Comment: The DuckDuckGo plugin for Chrome also blocks ga.

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow on from all the others who had an issue with the Monster Insights Wordpress plugin which renames `ga` to `__gaTracker`.

I didn't want to hardcode `__gaTracker` in my JS (to send an event to GA) - in case someone later removed the MonsterInsights plugin and my script just stopped working.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ga = typeof ga === "undefined" && typeof __gaTracker !== "undefined" ? __gaTracker : ga;
    ga('send', 'event', 'Order', 'Received', 'My cool product name');
</script>
```

The first line creates a var called `ga` which is either the original `ga` object or the `__gaTracker` object if `ga` does not exist. Note: if `ga` and `__gaTracker` both don't exist you will end up with the same error `ga is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

If you're no longer using Google Analytics, it's possible you accidentally left a `ga("send", "pageview");` in your code.

If you're not sure, in your theme directory try `grep -r "ga(" *`

If you actually want Google Analytics, I'm thinking you called the ga() function before it was defined, or for some reason Google Analytics is not loading at all.